# html: Images not loading in iPad Mini

Tags: html, image, ipad-mini

I've added some images on my html page, and they do not appear on the iPad Mini. I've tested the page on an iPad running iOS6, a galaxy tab 2 with android v4.0.4, and a couple of desktops, and all the images appear as they should.

The image tag i'm currently using is:

```
<img id="abc" src="img.png" alt=""/>
```

I am stumped by this issue. Am unable to find a solution as of yet...

Comment: Do you use the same **CSS** selector multiple times ( _#abc_ ) ?

Comment: @Vucko — What makes you think that might be the problem? It is a foreground image.

Comment: @Vucko - definitely not! and as Quentin mentioned, that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: To clarify, it works on an iPad but not an iPad Mini? Have you tried plugging it in and looking at the Safari mobile inspector?

Comment: @sanjaypoyzer I had tested the page on an iPad Mini again, but was unable to see the issue. I'll have to check again later, to see if it is consistent or not. The next time i get my hands on the iPad Mini (i don't own it :( ), i will surely check the debug tool. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  I found out that image file reference case-sensitivity differed between ipad mini and ipad.  Make sure the file reference has correct case.