# iPad not loading images

Tags: image, css, ipad, retina

I have an iPad with a Retina display and all things are loading nicely apart from some images (they don't show up in random).

What I have tried so far:

1. Use `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);` on those elements - **didn't work**
2. Use `data-at2x="<?= $img[0][1][0];?>"` on the `<img>`  tag - **didn't work**

What else could I try?

Comment: Have a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15764257/html-images-not-loading-in-ipad-mini

Comment: @Aruloci thanks, but that does not work for me.

Comment: How many images and what size do they have?

Comment: @Uooo multiple images and the size varies a lot - sometimes it's the logo that's not being shown, sometimes it's a thumbnail, othertimes it's a large image.

Comment: The reason I'm asking is because there is an [image size limit on iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4721899/1328300). I don't know how this behaves on newer iOS devices, though. However, if the sum of your image filesizes is big, this could be the reason.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the Apple naming convention in their "Resource Programming Guide" on page 46.

> The bundle- and image-loading routines automatically look for image
>   files with the @2x string when the underlying device has a
>   high-resolution screen. If you combine the @2x string with other
>   modifiers, the @2x string should come before any device modifiers but
>   after all other modifiers, such as launch orientation or URL scheme
>   modifiers. For example:
>
> - MyImage.png - Default version of an image
>     resource.
> - MyImage@2x.png - High-resolution version of an image
>     resource for devices with Retina displays.
> - MyImage~iphone.png -
>     Version of an image for iPhone and iPod touch.
> - MyImage@2x~iphone.png -
>     High-resolution version of an image for iPhone and iPod touch devices
>     with Retina displays.